# Не работает curl в МойСклад

Tags: php, мойсклад-api, php-curl

Никак не могу авторизоваться на МойСклад возможностями REST

```
$urlrest = 'https://online.moysklad.ru/exchange/rest';
    if ($ch = curl_init($urlrest) ) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,  dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'ХХХХ:ХХХХХ');
    $res = curl_exec($ch);


    curl_close($ch);
        echo $res;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Браузером пробовали зайти по указанному адресу? Видимо нет, так как увидели, что оно требует аутентификации (а Вам то авторизоваться нужно, а в коде нет имени-пароля... оно с воздуха ведь не возьмет). То есть, если я правильно помню php, нужна строка вида

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth_name.':'.$auth_pass);
```

Comment: нет, я пробовал ...
после добавления строки стало возвращать 413 ошибку.

хотя должно возвращать 404

Comment: решил проблему сам

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 

нужно было поменять 1 на 0

Comment: Поищите документацию - там все это должно быть описано. А просто так угадать - post или get - очень сложно.

Comment: я как раз и прочитал, 
всю по curl и самого API МойСклад